# MS Graph Report API getOffice365ActiveUserDetail - Users are missing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Following situation i have expierenced in several tenants:

with Application permission:

~ **35.000** users show regular activity in the tenant

**API:**  the *getOffice365ActiveUserDetail* API show ONLY **23.000** user objects with recent activity
--> even if you extend the duration from 7D to 180D, the amount of 23.000 users remain almost the same :(

**Questions:**
-Are there any undocumented limitations for this API in terms of number of users one can retrieve from this API?
-why does the change in the duration not change the total number of users in the dataset?

Any appreciate your help and feedback
thank you

Comment: I dont remember a documentation talking about this scenario. (1) Can you repro the issue consistently only for a set of users? (2) You notice the same issue in the portal.office.com's reporting feature (compliance & security section) as well?

Comment: Have you tried the reporting feature as i updated above?